# Ansible: Stop and Disable services if they are present

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to stop and disable a list of services only if they are installed. I'm calling the service_facts module to generate a list of running services and using filter "union"

```
- name: Include variables for Amazon Linux.
  include_vars: ../vars/test.yml

- name: populate service facts
  service_facts:

- name: start the service if it's enabled
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    enabled: no
    state: stopped
  loop: "{{ stop_services |union(services) }}"
  when: stop_services is defined
```

I'm getting an error **Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ stop_services |union(services) }}): can only concatenate list (not \"dict\") to list"**

Is there any other way to stop and disable a list of services only if they are installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is described accurately by the error message: `stop_services` is a list, and `services` is a dictionary. You can't just squash the two together. You will need to build a list of service names and compare your list of services to stop against that.

For example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    stop_services:
      - sshd.service
      - avahi-daemon.service
  tasks:
    - service_facts:

    - name: stop and disable a service
      service:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: stopped
        enabled: false
      when: "item in service_names"
      loop: "{{ stop_services }}"
      vars:
        service_names: "{{ services|dict2items|map(attribute='value.name')|list }}"
```

Comment: I had something quite similar except I would not loop on any non existing service. This would remove the `when` clause and the `vars`, only leaving the following `loop`: `{{ services | dict2items | map(attribute='key') | intersect(stop_services) }}`

Comment: I forgot about `intersect`! But I think they both end up in the same place.